# How to load an .exe as a .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

Can I just use?:

```
Assembly.LoadFile
```

Not sure if this is the way to do this?

But when I try that approach, it throws a `Could not load file or assembly "CustomControlLib"` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the business problem domain? Not, how do I solve this the way I want to solve this, but what is the motivation behind what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to load a standalone app into another app that will act as a child of the main app. I can do this using dll instead but this complicates things alot, for instance having to switch from standalone WPF app to a standalone control library is a lot of work and not easy to go back and forth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the dependencies are also loaded into the app domain. If they aren't located automatically, you can subscribe to [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) in order to find and load assemblies manually if needs be.

For example:

```
private Assembly AssemblyEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return locatedAssembly;
}
```

Also, I would consider using [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx), particularly [after reading this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3bdaf65c-520c-4a1a-a825-fc2ca2957bf3#58e799db-1ad0-4ae8-81df-bf4bb06cc43a) which has a strong assertion by nobugz and links to [some](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) good [reading](http://ogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx) (all dated but ought to still be withstanding for the most part.)

Comment: Thanks when I used LoadFrom now, I get a similar error but with this `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Comment: @Joan Venge: What platform are you on? x86 or x64? And what bitiness does the assembly target?

Comment: I am on Win7 x64. The assembly says it's x86, so you are right that might be the problem. But should I change it to any cpu or x64?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Assembly.LoadFrom()` dependencies will be loaded from the directory where assembly is located.

`Assembly.LoadFile()` is ignoring all other DLLs and exe files in the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can load a .Net exe the same way as you would load a Dll. The error you get is caused by dependencies of your exe. Make sure that the those dependencies can be found, i.e. are in your assembly search path.

Comment: They are but I use a 3rd party control and when I open its source control it uses other dlls that aren't present in my solution, but aren't these supposed to be taken care of automatically? Because the assembly is already built and added as a reference to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Assembly.LoadFile()`. Check your path.

Comment: And check to make sure any dependencies are in the execution path.